# Correct way to calculate triangle area from 3 vertices

Tags: python, geometry

Is this the correct way to calculate the area of a triangle given the 3 triangle points/vertices? The vertices will never be negative values.

```
def triangle_area(tri):
    x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = tri[0][0], tri[0][1], tri[1][0], tri[1][1], tri[2][0], tri[2][1]
    return 0.5 * (((x2-x1)*(y3-y1))-((x3-x1)*(y2-y1)))
```

Comment: use heron's formula

Comment: @Reblochon Masque Heron's formula is suitable when somebody have side lengths, not coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

It is necessary to add `abs` to this formula to avoid negative area value (sign depends on orientation, not on positive/negative coordinates)

Yes, this formula is correct and it implements **the best** approach if you have vertices coordinates. It is based on [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) properties.

```
def triangle_area(tri):
    x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = tri[0][0], tri[0][1], tri[1][0], tri[1][1], tri[2][0], tri[2][1]
    return abs(0.5 * (((x2-x1)*(y3-y1))-((x3-x1)*(y2-y1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost, but you need to take the absolute value at the end.
You're formula can be derived from the [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) which applies to any simple (no crossing edges, no holes) polygon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate a triangles area, you can calculate the surrounding rectangles area and substract the 3 triangles which have 90° angles around it:

```py
def triangle_area(tri):
    x_min = min([point[0] for point in tri])
    x_max = max([point[0] for point in tri])
    y_min = min([point[1] for point in tri])
    y_max = max([point[1] for point in tri])
    area_rectangle = (y_max - y_min) * (x_max - x_min)
    t1 = 0.5 * abs((tri[0][0] - tri[1][0]) * (tri[0][1] - tri[1][1]))
    t2 = 0.5 * abs((tri[0][0] - tri[2][0]) * (tri[0][1] - tri[2][1]))
    t3 = 0.5 * abs((tri[1][0] - tri[2][0]) * (tri[1][1] - tri[2][1]))
    return area_rectangle - t1 - t2 - t3
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [Herons Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)